# Is canceling supported through the Simba driver on BigQuery?

Tags: java, google-bigquery

Does the Simba BigQuery JDBC driver support canceling jobs via java.sql.Statement.cancel()?

If so, does the Simba driver block until the job is completely canceled?

BigQuery does have an API to cancel a job:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs/cancel

Thanks

Comment: Did you try it?!

Comment: Of course!  The queries don't look like they are being cancelled.

Comment: Please share your code and some example job ids.